# Thunderbird extension - How to use relative paths with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm developing my own Thunderbird extension.
The extension adds an .xml-file as an attachment to a Thunderbird mail (it works very well).
My only problem is that I don’t know how to use a relative path.

It looks something like that:

```
var file= 'C:\\...[… \\…]...\\chrome\\VHitG2.xml';
var attachments = [];
    attachments.push(FileToAttachment(file));
    AddAttachments(attachments);
```

If  the extension  is installed in a different path, the extension can’t work.
Doe’s anyone know how to use relative paths ?

Comment: Relative to what? Is that file part of your extension bundle?

Comment: Yes, it is part of my extension. It will be used by other people, so the installation-path of Thunderbird will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FileToAttachment()` function doesn't do magic, it is actually [very simple](http://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/b0b81ad1198d/mail/components/compose/content/MsgComposeCommands.js#l3507). I assume that you are talking about a static file that is part of your extension - it should be accessible under a URL like `chrome://myextension/content/VHitG2.xml`. Then you can simply create an [nsIMsgAttachment](http://doxygen.db48x.net/mozilla-full/html/d8/dca/interfacensIMsgAttachment.html) instance yourself using that URL:

```
var attachment = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messengercompose/attachment;1"]
                           .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIMsgAttachment);
attachment.url = "chrome://myextension/content/VHitG2.xml";
AddAttachments([attachment]);
```

Note that your extension doesn't need to be installed unpacked for that, you don't need an actual file on disk.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it with `attachment.url = "chrome://myextension@example.com/chrome/VHitG2.xml";`.  The attachmentbucked is filled with a file called “chrome://myextension@example.com/chrome/VHitG2.xml" I’m not able to open this attachment or to send the mail with the attachment (lack of authorization).

Comment: @MSKV: `chrome://` URLs don't work like that, please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration.

Comment: @ Wladimir Palant: I added `content attach chrome://myextension/content/VHitG.xml` to my `chrome.manifest` and it works! My problem now is that i can’t change the content of the .xml file with `NetUtil` and `FileUtils` (worked before).

Comment: I have no idea how to modify your code to get a `nsIFile` instead of an `nsiMsgAttachmet`.

Comment: @MSKV: You cannot get an `nsIFile` instance for something that isn't a physical file (it's inside a compressed archive). However, if you want content that you can change then maybe using [`data:` URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) will work.

Answer (score 0):

I used a very circuitous way to get the URL of the extension’s files:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
var test1 = FileUtils.getFile("CurProcD", ["VHitG2.xml"]);
var test2 = FileUtils.getFile("CurProcD", ["VHitG.xml"]);
var file1 = test1.path.replace(/VHitG2.xml/i, "extensions\\custom-toolbar-button@example.com\\chrome\\VHitG2.xml");
var file2 = test2.path.replace(/VHitG.xml/i, "extensions\\custom-toolbar-button@example.com\\chrome\\VHitG.xml");
var attachment1 = file1.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
var attachment2 = file2.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```